# ios 8 : When clicked inside UITextview, keyboard not popping but works well in ios 7

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios8

It is still working well in ios 7, UITextView is added to popover and displayed.

```
UITextView *textViewComment =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textViewComment.tag = 2001;
textViewComment.delegate = self;
textViewComment.frame=CGRectMake(15,60, 370,120);
textViewComment.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
[textViewComment setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
textViewComment.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
textViewComment.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
textViewComment.bounces = NO;
textViewComment.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
textViewComment.layer.borderWidth =1.0f;
[textViewComment addSubview:commentPlaceHolderLabel];
[popupViewController.view addSubview:textViewComment];
```

On ios8 adding textViewComment.keyBoardType = UIKeyboardAlphabet, textViewComment.enable = YES; didnt help. I dont know what mistake I am making. Is this new sdk bug? or my bug?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try :press command+k to show/ hide keyboard in simulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you working in the simulator ?

Because by default the hardware keyboard is selected and the simulator's won't show up.

You can change that by going into menu "Hardware" -> "Keyboard" and deselect "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Comment: It is hard to accept that this the answer but I have to. Its working for me as well( I just realized I was being silly n a little panic on ios 8 brought me to the conclusion of posting this Question)

Comment: Just started playing around with Swift and iOS 8.  Bless you for posting this. It was rather frustrating that super simple code was not working for no apparent reason.